# Prove $3^n > 2^n + n^2$ by Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, induction

> Prove that $3^n > 2^n + n^2; \forall n \ge 2$ using induction.

**Base Case:** $n=2$

$$3^2 > 2^2 + 2^2 \implies 9 > 8$$

**Inductive Step:**

$$\text{If } 3^k > 2^k + k^2; \forall n \ge 2 \text{ Then } 3^{k+1} > 2^{k+1} + (k+1)^2$$

So,

$$3^{k+1} = 3*3^k > 3(2^k + k^2) \text{ // By our inductive hypothesis}$$
$$= 3*2^k + 3k^2  > 2*2^k + 3k^2$$
$$=2^{k+1} + 3k^2 > 2^{k+1} + (k+1)^2 \text{ // How to show?}$$

**My Question:**

I feel like I know intuitively that $3k^2 > (k+1)^2$; $\forall n \ge 2$ but is there a better way to show this? Or a better way to conclude my proof in general? Thanks for any help the community can give. :)

Comment: Without induction: $3^n=(2+1)^n=2^n+n2^{n-1}+n(n-1)2^{n-3} +\cdots > 2^n+n+n(n-1) > 2^n+n^2$ for $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 5):

$$3k^2=k^2+k^2+k^2>k^2+k\cdot k+1\geq k^2+2k+1,$$ since $k\geq 2$.